# Can't get query results outside the function

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

I have this class in which i try to initialize array attributes with query results:

```
class data
minute: []
hour:   []
constructor:    () ->
    findMin = events.find({"aggr":"minute"}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(120)
    findHour = events.find({"aggr":"hour"}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(14)
    findMin.execFind (errMin, resMin) ->
        for recMin in resMin
            @minute.push recMin
    findHour.execFind (errH, resH) ->
        for recH in resH
            @hour.push recH
```

So i call `smth = new data()` and `console.log smth` and get an empty attributes and an error about undefined not having 'push' method. While i can understand an error i cant get why my arrays are empty. Dont get me wrong - i know this error causes them to be empty, but i tried several kinds of variants. And ive read about acync and callbacks, but still don't have a clue how to use callbacks not to 'alert' smth, but to use it afterwards. If you could help me with that or with some links that could - i would appreciate it SO much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want `minute` and `hour` to be instance variables?  They must be initialized in the constructor.  The way you're doing it now, they're on the `prototype`, so it won't work properly.  Try this:

```
class data
  constructor:    () ->
    @minute = []
    @hour = []
    findMin = events.find({"aggr":"minute"}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(120)
    findHour = events.find({"aggr":"hour"}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(14)
    findMin.execFind (errMin, resMin) =>
        for recMin in resMin
            @minute.push recMin
    findHour.execFind (errH, resH) =>
        for recH in resH
            @hour.push recH
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but it didn't work. It throws the same error about   using push of undefined. It seems like in those DB functions '@minute' and '@hour' are related to THOSE functions like they are local, not to the constructor.

Comment: @Eshnelbek Check my updated code.  You need a fat arrow to keep the correct `@`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. The one that is causing the error you are observing is that '@' inside of your two callbacks is not bound to your `data` instance, so you need to use `=>`. Secondly, and as pointed out by @AaronDufour, your `hour` and `minute` arrays are declared at the class level so they will be shared between every instance of `data`, which I doubt is what you want, so you need to move them into your constructor.

```
class data
  constructor: () ->
    @minute = []
    @hour = []

    findMin = events.find({"aggr":"minute"}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(120)
    findHour = events.find({"aggr":"hour"}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(14)

    findMin.execFind (errMin, resMin) =>
      for recMin in resMin
        @minute.push recMin
    findHour.execFind (errH, resH) =>
      for recH in resH
        @hour.push recH
```

Comment: Thx both of you, the problem was in this 'fat arrow'